# Docx4j Set a value on Bookmark

Tags: java, bookmarks, docx4j

I'm recently using the docx4j and i'm trying to set a bookmark on a Word document (it's my template file).

I already see the manual but i don't find the answer :S

I'm using version 2.8.1 and i'm getting a Bookmark based on the code available http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/bookmarks-and-templates-advice-t681.html (thanks, freemink).

```
  PbookmarkedParagraphInPart = findBookmarkedParagraphInPart(documentPart, "bookmarktest");

  // 3. copy the found paragraph to keep styling correct
  P copy = (P) XmlUtils.deepCopy(bookmarkedParagraphInPart);

  String ptext = "Testing";

  // replace the text elements from the copy
  List<?> texts = getAllElementFromObject(copy, Text.class);
  if (texts.size() > 0) {
     Text textToReplace = (Text) texts.get(0);
     textToReplace.setValue(ptext);
  }

  // add the paragraph to the document
  bookmarkedParagraphInPart.getContent().add(copy);
```

With this code my ptext is set on bookmark location but not inside of bookmark :/

I also retrieve the CTBookmark but there is no method to set a value here.

Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered (after a fashion) at your cross post at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/set-a-bookmark-text-t1526.html